# mongoose- how to sort on multi criteria w population

Tags: node.js, sorting, mongoose

I am trying to sort a 'role' document populated with 'group.name' first on group.name then on role.name

```
return this.find(query, { _group: 1, name: 1, _id:0 } )
  .populate('_group', 'name -_id')
  .sort({ '_group.name': 1, name: 1 })
```

but it does not work as expected , I get sorted only on role.name

```
ROLES:[
{"name":"NewRole"},
{"name":"NewRoleInGroup","_group":{"name":"GroupA"}},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupA"},"name":"admin"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupA"},"name":"employee"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupB"},"name":"employee"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupC"},"name":"employee"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupA"},"name":"manager"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupB"},"name":"manager"},
{"name":"visitor"}
]
```

I would like to get rather:

```
ROLES:[
// NO GROUP
{"name":"NewRole"},
{"name":"visitor"}.
// GroupA
{"_group":{"name":"GroupA"},"name":"admin"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupA"},"name":"employee"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupA"},"name":"manager"},
{"name":"NewRoleInGroup","_group":{"name":"GroupA"}},
// GroupB
{"_group":{"name":"GroupB"},"name":"employee"},
{"_group":{"name":"GroupB"},"name":"manager"},
// GroupC
{"_group":{"name":"GroupC"},"name":"employee"}
]
```

Thanks for feedback

UPDATE
As per @Talha comment :

Using aggregate , I am close to what I need... however , I get the group data inside an array, in a many-to-one relationship  there is only one group in this case ... how to project the group as the first object in the array :  "group": {}  or "group": {"name"; ..., "description": ...} ?

```
  return this.aggregate([
    { $match: query},
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'groups',
        localField: '_group',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'group'
      }
    }
    ,
    {
      $project: {
        'group.name': 1,
        'group.description': 1,
        name: 1,
        description: 1,
        _id: 0
      }
    },
    { $sort: { 'name': 1 } },
    { $limit: limit },
    { $skip: skip }
  ])


 ROLES: [
// NO GROUP
{"name":"NewRole","description":"NewRole description","group":[]},
{"name":"Visitor","description":"no permissions","group":[]},
// GROUP A
{"name":"NewRoleInGroup","description":"NewRoleInGroup description","group":[{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}]},
{"name":"admin","description":"can RW group, user","group":[{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}]},
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":[{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}]},
{"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":[{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}]},
// GROUP B
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":[{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}]},
{"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":[{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}]},
// GROUP C
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":[{"name":"GroupC","description":"Description GroupC"}]}]
```

Comment: You're sorting on `_group.name` on the original query. The matching documents do not have `_group.name` till it gets populated. While they do have `name` and the sorting works on it. You may need to use  [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in aggregation pipeline to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks @Talha , got it .. I updated my question using aggregate .. I've still a little trick to find in order to get the group data as an object {} as there is only one group in the projected array...

Comment: found the solution... added an answer  thanks a lot for your valuable feedback

Answer (score 1):

I should use the following function w aggregate :

```
  return this.aggregate([
    { $match: query},
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'groups',
        localField: '_group',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'group'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        group: {
          $let:{
            vars:{
              firstGroup:{
                $arrayElemAt:["$group",0]
              }
            },
            in:{
              name:"$$firstGroup.name",
              description:"$$firstGroup.description"
            }
          }
        },
        name: 1,
        description: 1,
        _id: 0
      }
    },
    { $sort: { 'group.name': 1, 'name': 1 } },
    { $limit: limit },
    { $skip: skip }
  ])
  .exec()
  .then((list) => {
    return list;
  })
```

This output the correctly ordered list ( 1/ by group.name 2/ ny role.name ) with the group out of the lookup output array :

```
ROLES: [
// NO GROUP
{"name":"NewRole","description":"NewRole description","group":{}},
{"name":"Visitor","description":"no permissions","group":{}},
// GROUP A
{"name":"NewRoleInGroup","description":"NewRoleInGroup description","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"admin","description":"can RW group, user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
// GROUP B
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
{"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
// GROUP C
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupC","description":"Description GroupC"}}]
```